# nginx domain name is not showing

Tags: docker, nginx

I am new experimenting with docker and nginx and it seems that i cannot make Nginx.

context:

- there is 3 docker container run on docker compose (Nginx, frontend, and a Api backend)
- the website works fine with the IP address
- using the domain name redirects to the serveur IP

Problem :

I cannot make ngnix to display the name domain in the url bar, it displays the server IP

Not sure if it a docker issue or nginx conf.

THe ngnix con :

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;
server_name  domain-name.com ; 


# Frontend
location / {
    proxy_pass http://frontend-name:8080; # same name as network alias
}

# Backend
location /api {
    proxy_pass http://backend-name:5000/;  # <--- note this has an extra /
}

# You may need this to prevent return 404 recursion.
location = /404.html {
    internal;
}
}
```

the docker compose file :

```
version : "3"


networks:
  isolation-network:
    driver: bridge

services : 
  frontend :
    container_name : frontend
    build: ./PersonalWebsite
    ports :
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
           isolation-network:
              aliases:
                  - frontend-name


  backend :
    container_name : backend
    build : ./API/test
    ports :
      - 5000:5000
    networks:
           isolation-network:
              aliases:
                  - backend-name   


  nginx-proxy:
      depends_on:
          - frontend
          - backend
      image: nginx:alpine
      volumes: 
          - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      networks:
           isolation-network:
              aliases:
                  - proxy-name
      ports:
          - 80:80
          - 443:443
```

any ideas ?